# removeFromParent doesn't work with SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to remove a sprite when I tap a button in my scene. The button is only enabled if the player collides with an item. This is the code for add and removes the sprite:

```
var imageShown = false
var imageForRiddle = SKSpriteNode()

func buttonAPressedForItem(item: WorldItem){
    if item.riddleImage != ""{
        imageForRiddle = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: item.riddleImage), color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.frame.size.height / 2))
        if !imageShown{
            imageForRiddle.position = player.position
            imageForRiddle.zPosition = 150
            self.addChild(imageForRiddle)
            imageShown = true
            print("Sprite added!")
        }
        else{
            imageForRiddle.removeFromParent()
            imageShown = false
            print("Sprite removed!")
        }
    }
```

The behaviour should be that if I touch the button, the image shows up. And if I touch the button again, the image dissapears. But the only thing happens is that the image shows up when I tap the button but never removed. When I click 3 times, I see the image 3 times. Both print statements are executed, so the `imageForRiddle.removeFromParent` is definitely called.

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: That's not how you specify a node in Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a new imageForRiddle on each tap with:

```
imageForRiddle = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: item.riddleImage), color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.frame.size.height / 2))
```

So, you are making a new image, then removing it (but, it was never added, so that is ignored).

You need to use the property you made to store the image and make sure to make only one and remove and add the exact same object.

Something like:

```
var imageForRiddle: SKSpriteNode? = nil
```

then,

```
if imageForRiddle = nil {
    imageForRiddle = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: item.riddleImage), color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.frame.size.height / 2))      
}
```

and then unwrap imageForRiddle when you use it.

Comment: Was about to reply the same thing (: nice shot

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks for the help!